# How do I calculate the work required to maintain a certain speed?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, energy-conservation

Asking this specifically for this one problem I am having trouble understanding. The question states:

A $350\mathrm{\ kg}$ car moves at a constant speed of $40\mathrm{\ m}/\mathrm{s}$ along a $7\mathrm{\ km}$ road against the frictional forces of $75\mathrm{ N}/{kg}$. How much work is done on the car to maintain the speed?

Now my logic for this question is, in order for the car to maintain its speed, the work would have to equal the work done by the friction force, so it can be in equilibrium. So $W_{\mathrm{friction}}=F\cdot s=(75\mathrm{\ N}/\mathrm{kg})(350\mathrm{\ kg})(7000\mathrm{\ m})=183750000\mathrm{\ J}$. Although I am a bit unsure of my answer since the result seems very large. Is this the correct way to approach this question?

The second part of the question asks the total work that is required for the same car to travel up a 7km ramp of incline 30 degrees while maintaining a speed of $40\mathrm{\ m}/\mathrm{s}$ and experiencing the same friction force.

Here I am unsure of how to do this question. My solutions say that you need to add the work done by friction to the gravitational potential energy of the car after $7\mathrm{\ km}$, but why do you need to do this? Isn't all the work that is required equal to the work of gravity acting on the car + the work of friction?

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't all the work that is required equal to the work of gravity
> acting on the car + the work of friction?

Hint: Per the work-energy theorem, the net work done on the car is still zero, but now in addition to the negative work done by friction, there is the negative work done by gravity.

Hope this helps.